# Redis Lua Script getting deleted every week

Tags: redis

I have loaded a Lua script into Redis using `SCRIPT LOAD` command and execute it using `EVALSHA`. However script is getting deleted after a period of 1 week. Is there any way other than `SCRIPT FLUSH` to remove the script? Are the script persistence between reboots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there any other way other than SCRIPT FLUSH to remove the script?**

For now, the answer is *no*.

**Are the script persistence between reboots?**

[No](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL):

> Also, as already mentioned, restarting a Redis instance flushes the
>   script cache, which is not persistent. However from the point of view
>   of the client there are only two ways to make sure a Redis instance
>   was not restarted between two different commands.

The application layer should be responsible of loading scripts to Redis after a reboot.